# matlab plot matrix line style

Tags: matlab, plot

```
phi2=[.890, .698, .859, .824, .637, .714, .827, .803];
phi3=[.680, .650, .790, .790, .620, .680, .740, .680];
phi4=[.859, .735, .825, .830, .628, .731, .842, .747];

phi=[phi2 phi3 phi4];
phi=phi';

plot(phi2,'+--')
hold on
plot(phi3,'x--')
plot(phi4,'s--')
axis([1 8 0 1])

set(0, 'defaultTextInterpreter', 'latex');
legend({'$C=2$','$C=3$','$C=4$'},'interpreter', 'latex', 'Location','SouthEast')
xlabel('$\phi(t)$');

hold off
saveas(gcf, 'phi(t)', 'pdf') %Save figure
```

Is there a way to plot the graph using plot(phi) ?
What I don't know is how to specify the line style (+--,x--,s--) in a single plot command.

And the axises looks too close to the edge. I could adjust it like

```
axis([0.9 8.1 0 1])
```

But can Matlab automatically adjust it?

Thanks!

Comment: What I usually do with the axis is something like: axis([min(phi(:)) max(phi(:))]*1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
phi=[phi2; phi3; phi4;];
plot(phi, {'+--','x--','s--'});
```

Regarding the axis, there are only a few way Matlab can automatically adjust leaving some space, like for example:

```
axis('normal')
axis('auto')
```

As you seem to want a margin on the x axis, you probably will have to do you own (using min/max/length of your data).

Comment: that's exactly what i need, thanks. I just noticed in my post, there was an error of the code. phi=[phi2 phi3 phi4]; should be phi=[phi2; phi3; phi4;];